# Is it better to call sort descending or just to sort a list and reverse it?

Tags: list, sorting, f#, reverse

The `List` module contains the `sortDescending` function that sorts a list from high to low. I read that it is faster just to sort the list and then reverse it. So I tried it and that seems to be the case.

```
 [1.0..1000000.0] |> List.sortDescending;;
Real: 00:00:00.322, CPU: 00:00:00.328, GC gen0: 10, gen1: 4, gen2: 0

[1.0..1000000.0] |> List.sort |> List.rev;;
Real: 00:00:00.243, CPU: 00:00:00.250, GC gen0: 15, gen1: 7, gen2: 0
```

(I tried many times, these values are typical)

Is there any reason to use `sortDescending` instead of just sorting the list and then reversing the result?

Comment: I would test here with a random test - here the input is already sorted, so you would expect sort then rev would be faster, but this may not be true with unsorted data.

Comment: I tried with random floats and got the same speed difference.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, sorting and reversing should only be faster for things that don't have identity (like integers and floats). If you look at the source on [github](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp) (see list.fs and local.fs), both copy the list into an array, sort the array and then recreate the list.

When you use `sortDescending` it sorts the array with `stableSortInPlaceWith`, which always uses `stableSortWithKeysAndComparer`.  This function, after the sort makes a copy of the result and adjusts duplicate items so they are in the original order.  It's a [stable sort](http://cs.smu.ca/~porter/csc/common_341_342/notes/sorts_stable.html) so duplicate items won't move around.

Sort uses `stableSortInPlace`, which has an optimization to detect things like floats with no identity so there's no need to use a stable sort; no second copy is made making it faster.  If it was a list of objects, `List.sort` then uses `stableSortWithKeysAndComparer` so it should be the same speed as List.sortDescending but then slower because of the reverse.  For my tests it was slower but hard to really tell for sure as my VM is on shared infrastructure and was giving wildly different results.

```
 [1.0..1000000.0] |> List.map Some |> List.sortDescending;;
Real: 00:00:13.616, CPU: 00:00:13.275, GC gen0: 146, gen1: 12, gen2: 5

 [1.0..1000000.0] |> List.map Some |> List.sort |> List.rev;;
Real: 00:00:17.727, CPU: 00:00:17.316, GC gen0: 149, gen1: 15, gen2: 6
```

As pointed out in the comments, the list is already sorted making the `List.sort` much faster (last I looked, .NET used a quick sort for arrays, which is fast if already sorted).  However, even if you reverse the list first, `List.sort |> List.rev` is still faster than `List.sortDescending` when it's a list of doubles.

One more note, the two are not actually equivalent for all cases. Because it's a stable sort, the duplicate items will be in the same order after `List.sortDescending`, but they'll be reversed by `List.sort |> List.rev`.